# How to work with 60,000+ rows in Deneb Vega-Lite?

Tags: powerbi, visualization, vega-lite, vega, deneb

I'm relatively new to Deneb, and currently, I'm trying to create a stream graph using Vega-Lite from a dataset that contains over 60,000 rows. I've noticed that in Vega-Lite, the maximum number of rows is limited to 10,000, which means I cannot display all the data on the graph (the x-axis should span from 2017 to 2023). Is there any workarounds so I can display all the data? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tws0O.png)

I've tried finding the solution on the internet, but I haven't found the answers yet.

Comment: https://deneb-viz.github.io/dataset#data-row-limits

Comment: You should add it as an answer